# Input binding is not working in angular while passing data from parent to child

Tags: angular

I am using DevExtreme angular and below is the code which I am using to pass Input Property from parent to child.

**Parent.html**

```
<add-edit-paper-stock (change)="changeHasChanges();"
    *ngFor="let productCodeProfilePaperStock of productCodeProfilePaperStockRollFedList; let i = index"
    [productCodeProfilePaperStock]="productCodeProfilePaperStock"
    (remove)="removePaperStock(productCodeProfilePaperStock.SortOrder,productCodeProfilePaperStock)"
    [entityIdSelected]="selectedEntity">
</add-edit-paper-stock>
```

**Parent.ts**

```
//This method is called from a dropdown on value change

getJobPrefixListByEntityId(event: any) {
    this.selectedEntity = this.selectBoxEntity.value;
}
```

**Child.ts**

```
//In child, I want to call a function after value for the entityIdSelected has been set. But, the debugger is not hit and the function is also not being called.

export class ProductCodeProfilePaperStockComponent {
    @Input() set entityIdSelected(value: number) {
        debugger
        this.getPaperStockListByEntity(value);
    }
}
```

```
//Child component selector

@Component({
    selector: 'add-edit-paper-stock',
    templateUrl: './product-code-profile-paper-stock.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-code-profile-paper-stock.component.css']
})
```

Comment: What is child component class name and child component selector(selector in `@component({...}))`

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti I have updated my question, please see is this what you have asked for?